# Could NOT find dynamixel_controllers in ROS

Tags: ros, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'am working in Ros melodic. I was trying to do 'catkin_make' in my workspace , but it showed me an error be like  :

```
-- Could NOT find dynamixel_controllers (missing: dynamixel_controllers_DIR)
-- Could not find the required component 'dynamixel_controllers'. The following CMake error indicates that you either need to install the package with the same name or change your environment so that it can be found.
CMake Error at /opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
Could not find a package configuration file provided by
"dynamixel_controllers" with any of the following names:

dynamixel_controllersConfig.cmake
dynamixel_controllers-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "dynamixel_controllers" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH
or set "dynamixel_controllers_DIR" to a directory containing one of the
 above files.  If "dynamixel_controllers" provides a separate development
package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.
```

I've already had the dynamixel directory in my workspace.
Does anyone know how to solve it ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/363618/could-not-find-dynamixel_controllers-in-ros/) by [jenanaputra](https://answers.ros.org/users/58305/jenanaputra/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2020-10-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

if you look an the pkg page you see
http://wiki.ros.org/dynamixel_controllers

that it is only sopported until ros kinetic.

---

Originally posted by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) with karma: 1999 on 2020-10-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0